# SQL Server Service Account Change using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have prepared below script to change sql server service account. But the service is not stopping and starting when i run below script. Any diea? is there any beeter way to do this. is there any alternative for Sleep. We don't know how much service takes to stop and start. Is there a way to keep powershell to wait until service completely 
stops/starts.

```
$Services = Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -ComputerName "." | Where { $_.name -eq 'MSSQLSERVER' }    
ForEach($Service in $Services)    
{             
$StopStatus = $Service.StopService()
Sleep 15
If ($StopStatus.ReturnValue -eq "0")
 {write-host "$Service -> Service Stopped Successfully"} 
$ChangeStatus = $Service.change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$ServiceAccount,$Password,$null,$null,$null)
If ($ChangeStatus.ReturnValue -eq "0")
 {write-host "$Service -> Sucessfully Changed Service Account"}
$StartStatus = $Service.StartService()
Sleep 25
If ($ChangeStatus.ReturnValue -eq "0")
{write-host "$Service -> Service Started Successfully"}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see if the service is stopped ( or started ) in a loop and then proceed:

```
$sleepCounter = 1
While((Get-Service $serviceName).status -ne "Stopped" ){
        Write-Host "Waiting for service to stop. Attempt $sleepCounter of 20"
        sleep 1
        if($sleepCounter -eq 20) { break }
        $sleepCounter++
}
```

Also, you can do the following to get the service instead of using `where-object`

```
$svc=gwmi win32_service -filter "name='$serviceName'"
```